# Error when invoking generic getInstance method in TypeScript with protected constructor

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm attempting to implement a generic `getInstance` method in TypeScript for a singleton pattern. The goal is to have the `getInstance` method work with a `protected` constructor, allowing derived classes to utilize the pattern. However, I'm encountering an error when invoking the `getInstance` method.

```
class Singleton {
  private static instance: Singleton;
   
  protected constructor() {}

  // with the public modifier this method works fine
  public static getInstance<T extends Singleton = Singleton>(this: new () => T): T {
    if (!Singleton.instance) {
      Singleton.instance = new (this as new () => T)();
    }
    return Singleton.instance as T;
  }
}

class Child extends Singleton {
  someMethod(): void {
    console.log("Child method called");
  }
}

Child.getInstance(); // Error
```

The error occurs on the line `Child.getInstance();` with the following message: `The 'this' context of type 'typeof Child' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'new () => Child'. Cannot assign a 'protected' constructor type to a 'public' constructor type.`

Is there a way to resolve this error and achieve the desired behavior of the generic getInstance method with a protected constructor?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKCWA7A5iApgFwPaOgbwFgAoaaABwCd4A3MDNaCDO%20YaJJsRYNALjiSpMOANzFipSlnrB6AE2jAcTCgFdZWCgAoAlPmgBfcSXKqARiFaNmGK8kwBJRJ25oAPABVoaAB71EcjAIKOjYuAC8AiHCiAB8WhgAFvAQ-IhoAO7QutDhsdAeOvxehCak8ABm2QCEwUJhAHQczK56paQdUfU4Tc4tPLnQ6Vl1oTi6YmWGEh0UmKoUuKMxvS4DkAWTpAakxEZExKCQMADCySAKvv6BXWO47YxYALZoALKYiVhyuvzUWPAKB6kJTOLDoBogLDILQAIjO8Au0BeSS%20ijAIHQchhOi20yI%202I8IuDXsGCcazQuiAA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution to my problem. Maybe it's not the best way to do it, but it works:

```
public static getInstance<T extends typeof Singleton>(this: T): T['prototype'] {
    if (!Singleton.instance) {      
      Singleton.instance = new (this as T)();
    }
    return Singleton.instance;
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdiAknAzsAhnAxhAKuCAHlyggA9gI4ATFKAbyjACcB7YdggLikxCgC%20APigBeKLgDaAIhbtOkaQF0A3AFgAUJqwAbdCjoBlAJZwA5jogc4DTVCbNjAN3SUoaV8axRTH7BB4Tc0trdS0NezlKLEpqKCxWVGBmAFcY1mYACgBKBkFNOyYUgCMdL3cMYHKzK2Q-HGJSCipaKFBIVgAzKCCLK0ShTOAAC2MUHlxsickAciiFCBmlWwj7H27MgEJekMSAOl8Mf1zGNftCs53%20uAOkzBwxKDgIAHcoIdG6fQlsnLCzgQXKDMKwpZg2K7WW71CD-QTnDSA8K6fR0ADCox0cXIlBoRlMfWsK3sKFYAFsIABZKzDVjUHI8JysYxxehAhKoViWPY6VhmTLSDHGLFQCkjOnxdA6SzUaTZOFIpGaIVYvY1YB1I44HJ7UkU6ni%20nyoA)